# How To replace Space by '+' sign using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a program in javascript which converts `<a href=''>Hello how are you</a>` into `<a href='hello+how+are+you'>hello how are you</a>`
After searching for it I found this code but it didn't work.

```html
<a id='text' href='output'>is you good</a>
<a href=''>is you good</a>
<script>
$text = getElementById("demo").innerHTML ;
$output = str_replace(" ", "+", $text);


</script>
```

Comment: Please do a simple web search first before asking questions. There is no such method as `str_replace()` in javascript and the proper method is not hard to find on the web...along with examples

Comment: You are mixing up php and javascript. You are looking for `String.prototype.replace(/ /g,"+")`

Comment: here what i want to make `<div class="tm-ctt-text"><a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=hello+how+are+you.&amp;via=denharsh&amp;related=denharsh&amp;url=https://www.something.com/" target="_blank">how are you.</a></div>
<p><a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=hello+how+are+you.&amp;via=denharsh&amp;related=denharsh&amp;url=https://www.shoutmeloud.com/" target="_blank" class="tm-ctt-btn">Click To Tweet</a></p>
<div class="tm-ctt-tip"></div>`

Comment: *"here what i want to make"* .... this is not a free code writing service. Do some research first

Comment: append it to original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"demo" is not an id that exists in your example. Also, I'm fairly certain you are trying to use php as javascript in there.

```
<a id='demo' href=''>is you good</a>

<script>
  const spaceToPlus = (content) => {
    return content.replace(/ /g, '+');
  }
  let anchor = document.getElementById('demo')
  let attributeHref = spaceToPlus(anchor.innerHTML);

  anchor.setAttribute('href', attributeHref);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementById() method needs to be called on a document object.

Basic googling would solve the problem. Please do some research before posting here.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

Answer (score -1):

Minimal example. Using regex to replace all spaces.

```html
<a id='text' href='output'>is you good</a>
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
console.log(text.replace(/[\s]/g, "+"));
</script>
```